# Fonts problem after install EN LIP in Windows 10 and office 2013

Tags: excel, vba, windows-10

I brought notebook with localized Croatian Windows 10 which make mi trouble with poor translation of English words. (I'm sys admin and used to use English.) So I downloaded LIP (language interface pack) for English. After install it, I got trouble with some windows and other application system dialog that do not show Croatian letters. It show some Chinese or similar characters.

Most problematic is MS Excel 2013 where I have lot of vba code, and I'm unable search any string with at least one HR char.
Also, my MsgBox show same chars as I already described

[image: MsgBox[1]]

VBA code:

```
Sub proba()

msg = MsgBox("Message with HR fonts: čćžšđČĆŽŠĐ" & vbCr & "(Should show ÄŤÄ‡ĹľĹˇÄ‘)", vbOKOnly, "MsgBox")

End Sub
```

Try to install HR LIP or EN LIP again or reinstaling fonts does not result success. I even install HR Office Language HR but nothing change.

Have someone experience with such a problem who can help me where should I look for solution. There is always option to reinstall windows, but this is last option after I exhaust all other options.

Comment: *This is how the VBA editor works*. The only way is to figure out the Unicode values of the characters you need then specify that in the strings. That would be something like `ChrW(1492) & ChrW(1493) & ChrW(1512)` Note: These are *not* Croatian characters, they're just non-Latin characters codes I happen to have in some test code on my machine. This example simply shows how to use Unicode in a string on an installation that does not support a particular character set.

Comment: The problem manifest on office vba as well, but is more wide. As I can figure out, I have problem with system fonts. Maybe I have wrong, but everything lead to this conclusion. I saw in other application dialog boxes problem with fonts, but those problems does not bother me. 
I'll change system fonts and see what will happened.